# Telegram bot double /start

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot and it works correctly. But if you send one more time /start it begins to answer twice the same thing. How can I repair that?

Comment: it's hard to help you if we can't check the code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. You should post your code if you want some help...

Answer (score 0):

Except first automatically `/start`, users can click that blue text or input themselves, there is no way to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent 2nd reply to the `/start` or to change it slightly you can simply create a record in DB/memcache/somewhere for a user with a flag/counter and check if it's the first attempt.

For example in my bot [@DebtsTrackerBot](https://t.me/DebtsTrackerBot) I'm asking user to choose language just on the first `/start` and safe chosen locale to user profile in DB.